# FXML choicebox with translations

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a Choicebox defined in FXML with some static choices. Is it somehow possible to define the translations for each value in the FXML?

My current code looks something like this:

```
<ChoiceBox fx:id="category">
    <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="Message" />
            <String fx:value="Request" />
            <String fx:value="Error" />
        </FXCollections>
    </items>
</ChoiceBox>
```

Now I would like to use the translations directly like this:

```
<ChoiceBox fx:id="category">
    <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="%category.message" />
            <String fx:value="%category.request" />
            <String fx:value="%category.error" />
        </FXCollections>
    </items>
</ChoiceBox>
```

Sadly this does not work.

Is something similar possible? How?

As an alternative I could create that list in the Controller#init method, but I would prefer to not do that.

Comment: I think this was asked recently, though I can't find it now, and the conclusion was that resource resolution does not work with `fx:value` (sadly). You probably do have to do this in the controller.

Comment: Hmm, well, maybe I have a workaround...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fx:value` attribute will only interpret literal strings, so it will not be able to resolve resources or expressions. IMHO this is a flaw in the design.

I have found this somewhat circuitous workaround. You can create a map with the resources you need, and then just use a  `<fx:reference>` to access elements of the map:

```xml
<fx:define>
    <HashMap fx:id="rscBndl" 
        message="%category.message"
        request="%category.request"
        error="%category.error" />
</fx:define>

<ChoiceBox >
    <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <fx:reference source="rscBndl.message" />
            <fx:reference source="rscBndl.request" />
            <fx:reference source="rscBndl.error" />
        </FXCollections>
    </items>
</ChoiceBox>
```

---

Here's a SSCCE:

ResourceTest.fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>

<?import java.lang.String ?>
<?import java.util.HashMap ?>

<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

    <fx:define>
        <HashMap fx:id="rscBndl" 
            message="%category.message"
            request="%category.request"
            error="%category.error" />
    </fx:define>
    <top>
        <ChoiceBox >
            <items>
                <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                    <fx:reference source="rscBndl.message" />
                    <fx:reference source="rscBndl.request" />
                    <fx:reference source="rscBndl.error" />
                </FXCollections>
            </items>
        </ChoiceBox>
    </top>
</BorderPane>
```

resources.properties:

```
category.message = Message
category.request = Request
category.error = Error
```

ResourceTest.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ResourceTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        ResourceBundle resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources");
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ResourceTest.fxml"), resources);
        Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load(), 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx. How did you find that solution? Try and error or is there somewhere a good book or documentation on this topic?

Comment: I just used the [FXML documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html) and pieced the rest together